# How to get guesses randomly generated

Tags: java

I am somewhat new to Java still and have a lab that needs to simulate a lottery game that generates a number between 1-10. It first asks the user how many tickets do they want to purchase and then asks them if they want the computer to generate the guesses for them, if yes then it will generate the guesses and reveal the winning numbers. If the user says no, then the user will input the guesses themselves and will show the winning numbers.

I am having a problem figuring out how to do the code for when someone enters yes or no. Should I do a do while loop?

Here is what I have as code right now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    double TICKET_PRICE = 2.00;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the State of Florida Play10 Lottery Game. Ticket Price: $" + TICKET_PRICE);

    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like to purchase?");
    int ticketsPurchased = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter " + (ticketsPurchased) + " to confirm your credit carde charge: ");
    int creditCardCharge = input.nextInt();

    if (ticketsPurchased != creditCardCharge) {
        System.out.println("Wrong number, please enter again: ");
        return;
    }
    if (ticketsPurchased == creditCardCharge) {
        System.out.println("Thank you. Your credit card will be charged $" + (ticketsPurchased * 2));
    }
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    int winner;
    winner = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));



    System.out.print("Would you like the computer to generate your guesses? Enter 'Y' or 'N': ");
    String computerGeneratedGuess = input.nextLine();

    int guess = 0;
    int winCtr = 0;
    String output = "";
}
```

Here is the algorithm:
1. Get number of tickets to purchase,
calculate and confirm credit card charge.
2. Generate random winning integer and
either generate random guesses or prompt
user for guesses.
3. Report the winning number, the winning
tickets, total winnings, total losses, and
allowable deduction

Here is the lab its self:
[Lab05 Lottery game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymzFH.png)

Comment: Well, you'll need a loop to deal with multiple tickets but whether they want auto-generated or provided numbers is independent of that. The yes/no part could just be an `if`. If they want to provide them, prompt them; if not, generate them.

Comment: Yes, every time you ask the user to type something, you should validate that what they entered is valid, and get them to re-enter it (with appropriate message) if not.  Even `nextInt()` is not sufficient - after all, great they've typed an int, but what if they typed "0", or a huge number, or a negative integer.  All should cause re-prompting (so in fact, prompting for an integer and looping with error if incorrect, is going to be a commonly repeated bit of code in your project ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a boolean is convenient to control a loop like this. Something like:

```
boolean gameOver = false;
int theGuess = 0;
while (!gameOver) {
    if (computerGeneratedGuess == 'Y') {
        theGuess = //code to generate a random number
    }
    else {
        theGuess = //code to for user to enter a guess
    }
    if (theGuess == winner) {
        gameOver = true;
}
```